# Analysing words in dataset based on training data

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, fuzzywuzzy

I have a training dataset for eg.

```
Letter    Word
A         Apple
B         Bat
C         Cat
D         Dog
E         Elephant
```

and I need to check the dataframe such as
AD    Apple Dog
AE    Applet Elephant
DC    Dog Cow
EB    Elephant Bag

the instances `AD,AE,EB` are almost accurate (Apple and Applet are considered closer to each other, similar for Bat and Bag) but `DC` doesn't match.

Output Required:

```
Letters    Words               Status
AD         Apple Dog           Accept
AE         Applet Elephant     Accept
DC         Dog Cow             Reject
EB         Elephant Bag        Accept
```

How can I find these matches using Python.

Comment: What are the rules to consider two words close or not?

Comment: Close in meaning or some alphabetical mistake.

Comment: "*Close in meaning*" is a hard task.

Comment: 'Spelling' can work for time being.

Comment: Even spelling is far from easy. You consider "bag" and "bat" close, what about "bat" and "cat"? Should "bit" and "bite" match? What about "apple" and "aplpe"? That's why you should first define explicit rules.

Comment: Can I use any NLP Algorithm for this?

Comment: Probably, but you need to ask a specific question, it is currently too vague

Comment: Something like Fuzzy String Matching can be used here.

Comment: You have to answer @mozway's point. You need to define exactly how much linguistic distance constitutes "close". Search for existing Q&A on *\[python\] fuzzy string matching* or *fuzzywuzzy* package e.g. [How to compare strings from 2 dataframes, and create new column containing matching words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71550178/how-to-compare-strings-from-2-dataframes-and-create-new-column-containing-match/71550877)

Comment: 0.70 Fuzzy Match